# How to adress the right html input field with php

Tags: php

I would like to delete an user from a file. I generate the html form with the php code. Now, it reads the user from a file ann puts it in a email input field. 
 When I click the delete button after the user I choose, it should delete him out of the file.
 But I don't know how to do it that it takes the right user, because I generate it with a for.

From where does the php choose if the button is clicked?
By the way the $liste is an Array with all the users in it.

```
 echo '<form id=\"myform\" name=\"myform\">';
for ($j = 0; $j < count($liste); $j++) {
    echo '<input id=\"email\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"required\" value=' . $liste[$j][0] . '>';
    echo '<select name="permission">
                    <option value="admin">admin</option>
                    <option value="user">user</option>
                </select>';
    echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'submit\'>';
    echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'delete\' value=\'delete\'>';
    echo '</form>';

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

echo "Option doesn't work yet";

}}

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++){
        if ($liste[$i][0] == $liste[j][0]){
            echo $liste[$i][0].'deleted';
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the beggining you having some syntax to fix in your form tag (missing  method to get and action to some page)

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($liste); $j++) {
    echo "<form id=\"myform\" name=\"myform\" action=\"\" method=\"GET\">";
    echo '<input id=\"email\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"required\" value=' . $liste[$j][0] . '>';
    echo '<select name="permission">
                    <option value="admin">admin</option>
                    <option value="user">user</option>
                </select>';
    echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'submit\'>';
    echo '<input type=\'submit\' name=\'delete\' value=\'delete\'>';
    echo '</form>';

}



if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

echo "Option doesn't work yet";

}
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($liste); $i++){
        if ($liste[$i][0] == $liste[j][0]){
            echo $liste[$i][0].'deleted';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is this... there is so much more wrong than just that. In fact it's more broken now.

Comment: @DigitalChris I know that my code isn't really that good, but I just need a good idea how to do an action to the file if the delete button is clicked

Comment: I think he ment on my answer not on your problem so I try to edit it more